# Is posting a document with a hand signature insecure?

Tags: security, best-practices, privacy

Every once and a while, one of our departments would like to post a hand-signed document on the web site. Up until now I've scanned them in as a PDF and posted them without much thought, but recently I've become wary of doing so.

Is there an inherent danger in posting a document with a scanned signature? Am I creating a fantastic opportunity for fraud and forgery, or am I overreacting?

Comment: The potential concern of fraud based upon a signature in a PDF is beyond the scope of Pro Webmasters (see [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq)); you may want to review Bruce Schneier's [essay on signatures](http://www.schneier.com/essay-220.html) - particularly if individuals whose signatures are posted have authority to order the release of convicts.